# How does require statement impact memory usage and performance

Tags: node.js

I have four files in my project namely.

`1. main1.js
 2. test1.js
 3. main2.js
 4. test2.js`

So `main1.js requires test1.js` and `main2.js requires test2.js`. We have a function which is needed in `main1.js` and is present in `test2.js`. So is it worth requiring the whole `test2.js` for one function ? or should I just copy the same function into `test1.js` ?

I need to know how it will impact the memory or performance given that both `main1.js` and `main2.js` run at the same time

Comment: Do you use `main2.js` elsewhere? If not, then just copy that code inside `main1.js`.

Comment: elsewhere as in ? both are the part of same project and will be loaded into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it. It's incredibly unlikely to measurably affect your application.

A source file is only ever loaded once (i.e. requires are cached) and all the requires should generally be running only once at startup.

---

In your specific case where you're loading all the modules anyway, it makes no difference whatsoever. For organisational reasons you may want to take a third option and move the shared code into a separate module required by both test1 and test2.